# How to change aspxgridview batchedit browser alert into popup message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I am using aspxgridview, in that gridview i am using batchedit.

I change some values in the gridview and if i am going to next UI means it shows browser alert.

I want to display that browser alert into popup by using JsProperties or something can anyone help me.

This is my browser alert

[image]

I want to show my pop up like this.
This is the example of row updated event.
here i am using jsproperties in cliet side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript

```
function onInit(s, e) {
            s.GetUploadControl().viewManager.showValidationError = function (error) {
                lbl.SetText(error.text);
                popup.ShowAtElement(s.GetMainElement());
                //console.log('custom processing: ' + error.text)
            };
        }
```

aspx code:

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="popup" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="popup" PopupHorizontalAlign="Center" 
            PopupVerticalAlign="Middle" AllowDragging="true" HeaderText="Error">
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Red" />
            <ContentCollection>
                <dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lbl" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ClientInstanceName="lbl"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

mention this on binaryimagecolumn

```
 <ClientSideEvents Init="onInit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
//Instead of this default jquery alert you can use your custom fancy alert or confirmation box which has used in you screenshot above.
 alert(); 
});
```

Comment: Hi curiousdev, That is not working give another solution. second image is not a broser alert which is i posted on my question it is popup .

Comment: Ok to open this pop up which used in second image you are writing some jquery code right and use some jquery plugin for this?

Comment: i am using java script to open that. I am using that in End call back of gridview and get that in row update event. herethere is no event. how i am used to change browser alert to pop.  I dont know how to use that.

Comment: Ohh please have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/276739/2534646) this can't possible to change Default dialog box

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].

Comment: If i am using the above code i met same browser alert only